# Сортировка записей по id в php

Tags: php, сортировка, phpmyadmin

У меня есть две страницы статей на каждой странице по 15 статей, когда я добавляю статью в БД она добавляется на последнюю страницу, то есть что бы пользователь смог прочитать новенькую статью он должен дойти до последнего поста что не очень удобно когда статей в реальности тысячи. Как сделать чтобы добавленная мною статья в phpMyAdmin добавлялась на первую страницу?

Comment: А как сделать чтобы сортировка работала на самом сайте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В запросе к БД добавьте `ORDER BY id DESC`.

Comment: На каком это диалекте?

Comment: @0xdb, это SQL-запросы к базе данных

Comment: Дрполните пожалуйста ответ ссылкой, например,  на оф.-док. БД.

Comment: http://oracleplsql.ru/order-by.html

Comment: http://aam.ugpl.de/?q=de/book/export/html/158

Comment: Если ни разу не работали с SQL, то можете почитать https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=557
или посмотреть видео 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1SXV0Qy-MOI&list=PLi3gxGWPyGGQOBAp-n-zWaj6QZeFtXLHh&index=1

Comment: Спасибо большое! С величайшим интересом ознакомился с предоставленным материалом. Но, к сожалению, так и не нашёл предложенной Вами конструкции `SORT BY id DESC`. Пожалуйста, дополняйте текст ответа кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/814502/edit).

Comment: тьфу ты, ORDER BY id DESC, конечно. Ошибся немного

Comment: А как применить ORDER BY id DESC в самом коде php?

Comment: Если на чистом MYSQL писать, то соединяешься с базой данных, если в коде соединения с ней ещё нет (команда mysql_connect), выбираешь базу данных (mysql_select_db) и делаешь запрос(mysql_query(код SQL запроса)). Подробнее можно посмотреть тут: http://weblecture.ru/node/151

Comment: Но рекомендую использовать PDO http://komotoz.ru/uroki/php/pdo.php